# How do I assign events to new-generated buttons

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I did a click event that transforms my

```
<span>text</span>
```

into

```
<input type="button" id="buttonclick">
```

and then assigns another click event by doing this

```
$("#buttonclick").click(function(){
alert("hello"); });
```

It is supposed to alert "hello" after I click it but it doesn't. I guess the reason is that since the button is generated during run time, the `$("#buttonclick")` just can't locate where it is, which is proved by this experiment, I assign this click event to another button that is created during design time (in the html page), and it works. I have no clue why this is happening. Any helps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this:

```
$("#buttonclick").live('click', function(){
    alert("hello");
});
```